# How can I speed up this Linq to SQL query?

Tags: database, linq, linq-to-sql

So, I have a function that returns data for use in a GridView.  It takes ages to complete (about 25 seconds).  I think I've written it very badly and I need to optimise it so it runs faster.

This is the code:

```
        var pingresult = from p in db.GetTable<tblTBHealthPing>()
                         group p by p.ComputerAsset into g
                         select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.HealthPingTime).FirstOrDefault();

        var healthresult = from p in db.GetTable<tblTBHealthHeartbeat>()
                         group p by p.ComputerAsset into g
                         select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.HealthHeartbeatTime).FirstOrDefault();





        var query = (from t in TrackingBoardPCs()
                     where t.TrackingGroup == groupName
                     select new TrackingComputer
                     {
                         ComputerName = t.ComputerAsset,
                         IPAddress = t.ComputerIP,
                         Location = t.Location,
                         Pingable = (from p in pingresult where p.ComputerAsset == t.ComputerAsset select p.HealthPingResult).FirstOrDefault() ?? false,
                         PingTime = (from p in pingresult where p.ComputerAsset == t.ComputerAsset select p.HealthPingTime).FirstOrDefault() ?? DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100),
                         Username = (from p in healthresult where p.ComputerAsset == t.ComputerAsset select p.HealthCurrentUser).FirstOrDefault(),
                         CurrentWindow = (from p in healthresult where p.ComputerAsset == t.ComputerAsset select p.HealthCurrentWindow).FirstOrDefault(),
                         Uptime = (from p in healthresult where p.ComputerAsset == t.ComputerAsset select p.HealthUptime).FirstOrDefault()
                     }).OrderBy(t => t.Pingable);
        return query;
```

There's probably a better way of doing this, namely, dropping the first two vars (pingresult and healthresult) and bringing them in on the main query somehow, but I have no idea how. Any help would be great :)

Comment: Did you try to left join on `pingresult` and `healthresult` : see  something like that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323619/linq-to-sql-left-join-to-max-aggregate ? By the way, what's `TrackingBoardPCs` ? An `IQueryable` ?

Comment: Yeah its an IQueryable, that is, the result of a LINQ to SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely a good idea to embed the subqueries inside the main query.

When doing that, you'll notice that they are always joined to the `TrackingBoardPCs` record by `ComputerAsset`, so they don't need to `groupby` that field.

Here is IMO the equivalent query:

```
var query = 
    from t in TrackingBoardPCs()
    where t.TrackingGroup == groupName
    join p in db.GetTable<tblTBHealthPing>() on t.ComputerAsset equals p.ComputerAsset
    into pingInfo
    join h in db.GetTable<tblTBHealthHeartbeat>() on t.ComputerAsset equals h.ComputerAsset
    into heartbeatInfo
    let p = pingInfo.OrderByDescending(p => p.HealthPingTime).FirstOrDefault()
    let h = heartbeatInfo.OrderByDescending(p => p.HealthHeartbeatTime).FirstOrDefault()
    let tc = new TrackingComputer
    {
        ComputerName = t.ComputerAsset,
        IPAddress = t.ComputerIP,
        Location = t.Location,
        Pingable = p.HealthPingResult ?? false,
        PingTime = p.HealthPingTime ?? DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100),
        Username = h.HealthCurrentUser,
        CurrentWindow = h.HealthCurrentWindow,
        Uptime = h.HealthUptime
    }
    order by tc.Pingable
    select tc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think,your `pingresult` and `healthresult` type `iqueryable`. So your code going `db` this lanes:

```
PingTime = (from p in pingresult where p.ComputerAsset == t.ComputerAsset select p.HealthPingTime).FirstOrDefault() ?? DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100),
Username = (from p in healthresult where p.ComputerAsset == t.ComputerAsset select p.HealthCurrentUser).FirstOrDefault(),
CurrentWindow = (from p in healthresult where p.ComputerAsset == t.ComputerAsset select p.HealthCurrentWindow).FirstOrDefault(),
Uptime = (from p in healthresult where p.ComputerAsset == t.ComputerAsset select p.HealthUptime).FirstOrDefault()
```

If you use `ToList()` your data getting local memory and should be faster. Maybe you can use like this:

```
    var pingresult = from p in db.GetTable<tblTBHealthPing>()
                     group p by p.ComputerAsset into g
                     select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.HealthPingTime).ToList().FirstOrDefault();//ToList() gets data from db to local memory

    var healthresult = from p in db.GetTable<tblTBHealthHeartbeat>()
                     group p by p.ComputerAsset into g
                     select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.HealthHeartbeatTime).ToList().FirstOrDefault();//ToList() gets data from db to local memory
```